# EasyMock returning strange values

Tags: java, easymock

I am currently trying to learn how to use easymock. I have the following code:

```
List list = EasyMock.createMock(List.class);
EasyMock.expect(list.size()).andReturn(0);
EasyMock.replay(list);
EasyMock.verify(list);
```

This, to me at least, should work -- a list is initialized with nothing in it and the size should return 0. I get the following error, however:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expectation failure on verify:
size(): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

I thought this was weird, so I changed the 0 in the line to a 1 and reran the test. I got the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after `replay` and before `verify`, you need to invoke the code that uses your mock. That code needs to call the expected method (`size` in this case) and *only* that method. The error message means you set your mock up to expect a method call, but when you went to verify, you never called the method on the mock, which makes sense because you never used the mock.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Stupid beginner mistake I missed in the tutorials I was reading. Thanks!

Comment: @dorrene, np, thats why SO exists.